# Ignoring-watcher is not reflecting the change

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 4 folders in a certain path which consists of a single file which has a list of files and extensions to ignore.
I am using npm module ignoring-watcher,

The problem I am facing is that what ever I am changing in any of the folders, are not being reflected after changing, only 1 out of 4 folders is tracking the change.

Secondly, the ignoring watcher keeps on running for all the folders when any change event is triggered.

Below I have explained in detail.

I have 4 project folders:let's say

```
/path/to/project1

/path/to/project2

/path/to/project3

/path/to/project4
```

Every folder consists of 2 files that I want to ignore which I have provided in a separate file in every project folder.

```
/path/to/project1/.no_include

/path/to/project2/.no_include

/path/to/project3/.no_include

/path/to/project4/.no_include
```

I have made a separate file in a separate path for every project I made changes it will reflect and will trigger an event change, so to do this I have configured the ignoring-watcher module.

**config.js**

```
var ignoringWatcher = require('ignoring-watcher').createWatcher({


      dirs: [
               '../../path/to/project1',
               '../../path/to/project2',
               '../../path/to/project3',
               '../../path/to/project4',
        ],
        ignoreFiles: [
             '../../path/to/project1/.no_include',
             '../../path/to/project2/.no_include',
             '../../path/to/project3/.no_include',
             '../../path/to/project4/.no_include'

        ]

    });

ignoringWatcher
   .on('modified', function (eventArgs) { // Fired for any change event (add, delete, etc.)
        var type = eventArgs.type; // add | addDir | change | unlink | unlinkDir
        var path = eventArgs.path; // The full file system path of the modified file
        console.log(type, path);
        onClick(from, to, not_included); //It is a function call.
    });
```

**Problem1**: Now If I made any changes in project3 that are reflecting correctly but If I make any changes to project 1 & project 2 that is not reflecting.I am getting the event change in the console stating that this file has been changed but the changes are not reflected where I am saving the files, I am using rsync for that, this is working good for project3

**Problem2**: When I start the config.js file it gets started and the changes are triggered when I did not make any changes.

**Note**: I am calling `ignoringWatcher.startWatching()` wherever I am calling the `onClick()` method.